# Django VS-Eextenstion is not colorizing syntax inside cotation

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I am using Django extension to highlight my text. it works perfectly outside but fails to highlight inside citations.
[not working under cotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HptyU.png)

I expect if there is any solution to overcome this. I want it to highlight the code inside exactly as outside , what can i do to overcome this.